# Pandas: Groupby and Value Gains per Step

Tags: python, pandas, loops, group-by

Imagine a  sequential Game between two Teams, where each Team tries to throw the ball closer to the opposite zone. The playing field is 100 Meters long, the locations are always from the attacking side. If a player from the own team catches the ball, they can throw again until the other Team catches the ball. Now Team B starts to throw the ball until Team A catches it. The winner is decided by the sum of cumulative meters.

`df = pd.DataFrame([['Team A','Wes','20'],['Team A', 'Chang', '40'],['Team B','Ross','30'],['Team B','Robert','55'],['Team B','Ross','65'],['Team B','Robert','85']],columns=['Team Name', 'Athlete', 'Location']`

This game is pretty popular and its played regulary, the new data is always added to the same DataFrame and gets a unique game number in a new column.

Now i want to look for:

1. The Winner of each Match
2. The sum and mean of the distance gained per Athlete

Also we assume that if you catch the Ball from your opponent, you get the distance from your own zone as meters. In the example would Ross gain the 30 meters as he catched the ball 30 meters away from his zone. Last the starting point is random.

Using just one Game, i can get the info i need with:

```
g = df.groupby('game_number')
g1 = g.get_group(1)
g1['Distance'] = g1.shift(-1,fill_value=0)['Location'] - g1['Location'] 

g1.groupby('Athlete')['Distance'].agg(sum,mean)

g1.groupby('Team_name')['Distance'].agg(sum,mean)
```

So i created a new column to measure the distance each event created. But for all games this method doesnt work or is really slow.

I tried it with a for loop and .get_group(i) and `df.merge(g,how=left)` but that did not return any results in 5 minutes. Is there an more efficient way to do this?

**Edit Expected Output DataFrame**

I want to look into the future and add the distance of the throw to the row of the throw

[image: Expected Output]

Comment: The rules seem quite complicated… Please provide the expected output dataframe